# Wierd thing happens in my test of COM Hijacking

Tags: dll, com

I currently test the validity of COM Hijacking in win10, follow like this https://github.com/leoloobeek/COMProxy. I can success in doing COM Hijacking(clsid-hijack) in my computer-A, by adding hkcu:\software\classes\clsid{guid}\Inproc32 key of the wscript.shell (replace to my dll). However, when I used this dll to other computer-B , error came out when I tried to activate the wscript com.

Used the command: `$object = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell` ,and I got this error:
New-Object : Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {72C24DD5-D70A-438B-8A42-98424B88AFB8} failed du
e to the following error: 8007007e The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

The first I think is that compter-B is lack of dependencys of my dll, but I use the CFF explorer, finding all dependencys of dll exist on computer-B. I will be very grateful if someone tell me what happened in this situation.
BTW, I use computer-A to compile dll.

This is my first time to ask a question, and English is not my native language, If my words seem wired ,please forgive me :))

Comment: Be sure to deploy the Release build (not the Debug build).  And install the [C++ runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) or build with /MT

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you so much. I didn't notice that, I'm so dumb hahah!!

Comment: @HansPassant maybe this is a stupid question, but why cannot use the debug version of dll in this scenario, I think the realease version is just optimization of debug version, ty.

Comment: You can't install the debug version of the C++ runtime, the page I linked can only work for the Release build.